# Creating a ruby object from multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to create an object from several models which I can return using an active record query.  The aim being to use the results to create a CSV output file from a subsequent query.

Lets say I have a simple model of items which have a status.  The status is held with the ID as you would do in a normalised database.  An item would have many statuses and a status would belong to an item (to achieve the relationship).

I've put some data in to illustrate this:

```
Item (model)
============
id    status_id
---------------
1     1
2     2
3     3

Status
============
id    title
---------------
1     Available
2     Loaned
3     Missing
```

Basically I want to be able to return the data as follows in an object:

```
item_id    status_title
--------------------
1          Available
2          Loaned
3          Missing
```

I know I could achieve this using a "find by sql", however I was hoping this could be returned using active record and relationships.

I've had a look at trying to use delegate but couldn't get that to work (assuming that it would do what I need).

Anyone advise on if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `belongs_to` association:

```
class Item
    belongs_to :status
end
```

and use it in AR query:

```
Item.joins(:status).select('items.id as id, statuses.title as status_title')
```